# qr-code-styling error 'Field colorStops is required in gradient' when the value is given

Tags: javascript, hook, qr-code

I am trying to generate a QR code with [QR Code Styling](https://github.com/kozakdenys/qr-code-styling) library. The problem is that even though I am giving the values for gradient `colorStops`, it is still throwing the error:

`Field colorStops is required in gradient`

Here is the screenshot of consoled parameters and the error, please guide me what I am doing wrong here. My application is in phoenix-elixir and I am using JS Hook to integrate the library.

[image]